# how do i submit form elements to sever emidiately after filling a particular form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, flask

i have this mini flask application i am building and i have nested a form in another and i wish to submit the nested form using just javascript after i finish filling it.
i am trying to do this with javascript but currently what my script deos is it submits the nested form emidiately the page loads and when i fill the inputs it deosnt submit again.
bellow are my code for my html form, flask route to collect the form and the javascript

**HTml**

```html
<form method="POST" action="/skills" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <h3>Skills</h3>
  <form method="POST" action="/skills" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="skills">Skills (comma-separated)</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="skills" name="skills" required>
    </div>

    <h3>Work Experience</h3>
    <div id="work-experience">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="work-title-1">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-title-1" name="work_title_1" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="work-company-1">Company</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-company-1" name="work_company_1" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add a hidden submit button -->
    <input type="submit" style="display: none;">
  </form>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-start-date-1">Start Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-start-date-1" name="work_start_date_1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-end-date-1">End Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-end-date-1" name="work_end_date_1" required>
  </div>
  {% if ex_summary %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-end-date-1">description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="sumary" name="ex_summary" rows="8">{{ ex_summary }}</textarea>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-work-experience">Add Work Experience</button>

  <h3>Certifications</h3>
  <div id="certifications">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-title-1">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certification-title-1" name="certification_title_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-start-date-1">Start Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certification-start-date-1" name="certification_start_date_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-end-date-1">End Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certification-end-date-1" name="certification_end_date_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-description-1">Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="certification-description-1" name="certification_description_1" rows="4" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-certification">Add Certification</button>

  <h3>Projects</h3>
  <div id="projects">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="project-title-1">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project-title-1" name="project_title_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="project-description-1">Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="project-description-1" name="project_description_1" rows="4" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-project">Add Project</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Generate Resume</button>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Add event listener to the last input field
    var lastField = document.getElementById('message');
    lastField.addEventListener('blur', function() {
      submitForm();
    });

    // Submit the form when the last field is filled and the cursor is no longer in the field
    function submitForm() {
      var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
      var messageField = document.getElementById('message');

      // Check if the message field is filled
      if (messageField.value.trim() !== '') {
        form.submit();
      }
    }
  }); <
/script>
```

**route to handle the form in the main.py**

```
@app.route('/skills', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def work_ex():  
    skills = request.form.get('skills')
    print(skills)
    title = request.form.get(f'work_title_1')
    print(title)
    company = request.form.get('work_company_1')
    print(company)
    if title and company and skills:
        ex_summary = experienc_sumary(title, company, skills)
        print(ex_summary)

        return render_template('skills_experience.html',  ex_summary=ex_summary)
    return render_template('skills_experience.html')
```

if you notice i am trying to send the form to the main.py to use in a function then return the results back to the html form on the same page before the user finishes filling the information

Comment: What field in the form has the id "message"? And about the user interaction; who says that the user will fill in the form from the top to the bottom? Wouldn't it be better if the user could decide when to post the form?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form method="POST" action="/skills" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <h3>Skills</h3>
 
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="skills">Skills (comma       separated)</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"   id="skills" name="skills" required>
    </div>

    <h3>Work Experience</h3>
    <div id="work-experience">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="work-title-1">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-title-1" name="work_title_1" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="work-company-1">Company</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-company-1" name="work_company_1" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add a hidden submit button -->
    <input type="submit" style="display: none;">
  


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-start-date-1">Start Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-start-date-1" name="work_start_date_1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-end-date-1">End Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-end-date-1" name="work_end_date_1" required>
  </div>
  {% if ex_summary %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-end-date-1">description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="sumary" name="ex_summary" rows="8">{{ ex_summary }}</textarea>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-work-experience">Add Work Experience</button>

  <h3>Certifications</h3>
  <div id="certifications">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-title-1">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certification-title-1" name="certification_title_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-start-date-1">Start Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certification-start-date-1" name="certification_start_date_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-end-date-1">End Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certification-end-date-1" name="certification_end_date_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-description-1">Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="certification-description-1" name="certification_description_1" rows="4" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-certification">Add Certification</button>

  <h3>Projects</h3>
  <div id="projects">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="project-title-1">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project-title-1" name="project_title_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="project-description-1">Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="project-description-1" name="project_description_1" rows="4" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-project">Add Project</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Generate Resume</button>
</form>
```

Having nested forms like this isn't real a good automation. What about you having a single form for submitting all your inputs, since you are making a post request to one endpoint from your html.

```
<form method="POST" action="/skills" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <h3>Skills</h3>
 
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="skills">Skills (comma-separated)</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="skills" name="skills" required>
    </div>

    <h3>Work Experience</h3>
    <div id="work-experience">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="work-title-1">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-title-1" name="work_title_1" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="work-company-1">Company</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-company-1" name="work_company_1" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add a hidden submit button -->
    <input type="submit" style="display: none;">
  


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-start-date-1">Start Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-start-date-1" name="work_start_date_1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-end-date-1">End Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-end-date-1" name="work_end_date_1" required>
  </div>
  {% if ex_summary %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-end-date-1">description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="sumary" name="ex_summary" rows="8">{{ ex_summary }}</textarea>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-work-experience">Add Work Experience</button>

  <h3>Certifications</h3>
  <div id="certifications">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-title-1">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certification-title-1" name="certification_title_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-start-date-1">Start Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certification-start-date-1" name="certification_start_date_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-end-date-1">End Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certification-end-date-1" name="certification_end_date_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="certification-description-1">Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="certification-description-1" name="certification_description_1" rows="4" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-certification">Add Certification</button>

  <h3>Projects</h3>
  <div id="projects">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="project-title-1">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project-title-1" name="project_title_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="project-description-1">Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="project-description-1" name="project_description_1" rows="4" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-project">Add Project</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Generate Resume</button>
</form>
```

From your BE remove the last return statement you just need only this line:

```
return render_template('skills_experience.html',  ex_summary=ex_summary)
```

I hope this works out for you.

Comment: that's not really where my problem is 
i know nesting forms is not really advisable but my problem is that my javascript function submits the nested forms immediately i load onto the page and as such empty values are submitted to the server side 

so i am hoping someone can help me on how i can avoid the form submission immediately i load the page  and it should submit only when i finish filling the nested form

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default behaviour of your app from submitting immediately in your js.

```
< script >
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Add event listener to the last input field
        var lastField = document.getElementById('message');
        lastField.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault(),
          submitForm();
        });
    
        // Submit the form when the last field is filled and the cursor is no longer in the field
        function submitForm() {
          var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
          var messageField = document.getElementById('message');
    
          // Check if the message field is filled
          if (messageField.value.trim() !== '') {
            form.submit();
          }
        }
      }); <
    /script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version of your form. All the fields are required, meaning that all fields must have a value before the submit event happens. The event listener for the `blur` event will happen each time one of the inputs get out of focus. On this event I test if the form is valid aka. all the fields have a value. If the form is valid I "click" the hidden submit button and the submit event will happen.

Notice that the order of filling in the form field is up to the user. As soon as the last required field has a value and loses focus the submit event will happen.

I don't like the fact that the form submits when the user changes focus on the input elements, but you probably have a good reason for that design. I think you should let the user decide when the submit happens.

```js
// this event listener for the submit event is only for
// testing when the submit happens.
// remove it to continue the POST request to /skills
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit');
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('blur', e => {
  // test if the form is valid and can be submitted
  if (e.target.form.checkValidity()) {
    e.target.form.submit01.click();
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<h3>Skills</h3>
<form name="form01" method="POST" action="/skills" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="skills">Skills (comma-separated)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="skills" name="skills" required>
  </div>

  <h3>Work Experience</h3>
  <div id="work-experience">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="work-title-1">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-title-1" name="work_title_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="work-company-1">Company</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work-company-1" name="work_company_1" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Add a hidden submit button -->
  <input name="submit01" type="submit" style="display:none">
</form>
```